# No sound on fresh install of Debian

Tags: linux, debian, audio, i3

I'm using Debian with i3. I have both pulseaudio and alsa installed but I cannot get sound to output.

Answer (score 6):

`sudo alsactl init` worked for me in a similar situation. I believe sudo privileges were required for this. At the time I had these packages installed: `alsa-base`, `alsa-oss`, `alsa-utils`.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately and the volume is still set to mute after raising both the alsamixer and an xfce mixer I have installed.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian 9 and i3/LXQT I installed the packages `alsa-firmware-loaders`, `alsamixergui`, `alsaplayer-oss`, `alsa-utils`, `alsa-tools` and `alsa-tools-gui`, but this was probably overkill.
Then I just used `alsamixergui` to turn on the Master Volume (make also sure that the speaker icons above it are 'turned on', if you see them) and the appropriate speakers.

Comment: On my DEBIAN **alsamixergui** was sufficient, Also through the **apt-get install alsamixergui** , the **alsamixer** command line, just came back

Answer (score 0):

Some distributions ship alsa with the main channel muted. Check `alsamixer`.

Comment: Yeah I had checked that just forgot to put it into my question.

Comment: Don't forget to check all controls of all "cards" (push F6).

Answer (score 0):

One place to start is to use `pavucontrol` (install it if you don't have it) to check to what output your sound is sent. Under "Output Devices", the text next to the icon of a sound card should be something familiar (for me it is "Built-in Audio Analog Surround 4.0".

There might be options to change ports, if you have multiple speaker configurations. But that shouldn't make your volume mute, that should just change how the sound is ported to different speakers on your machine (if there are different options). Now, if the text next to the sound card icon is "Dummy Output", you might want to reload alsa ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426983/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-alsa-or-pulse-audio-by-default-switching-to-i3-wm) is a good explanation of what alsa and pulse-audio are).

Try running the command `sudo alsa force-reload`, and then **reboot** your computer (that part is important). Hopefully it should work after this - let me know if this works!

P.S. If you're new to Linux, i3 is a bit much to handle on top of everything else. Just keep this in mind - the creator, Michael Stapelberg, says so [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/manpage.html#_description) that i3 is meant for somewhat seasoned Linux users, so you might have a slightly more difficult time at first.